# Testing NHibernate CRUD Operations

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate

Hi I'm testing some CRUD operations in Nhibernate.

I have 3 tests in this order - add
update and delete.

When I test the update procedure I always get a fail as the object I just added is null.
Do I need to close the session or do a flush before doing the update test. Or is there a better way for me to do this.
Any help more than appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your tests should not be order dependent, nor should they interact with one another. Your just setting yourself up for trouble if they do. Eventually your test runner is going to change out from under you and the delete is going to run first. Try making each test its own beast and then rolling back the transaction in the teardown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush the session. That will make sure the item has been persisted into your database.

Also if you are using Fluent NH (which you might consider doing) you can get this out of the box - http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing
(or better with less hassle).